# AWS throws the following error: "bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, pip, command-line-interface

I'm not aware of anything on my system having changed, but the `aws` CLI tool has stopped working.

```
$ aws-bash: /Users/user_name/Library/Python/3.7/bin/aws:/usr/local/opt/python/bin/
python3.7: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I've tried `brew reinstall awscli` which is suggested elsewhere, but with no luck.

Comment: If you edit `/Users/user_name/Library/Python/3.7/bin/aws` you'll presumably see that its shebang indicates `/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7` which no longer exists (either you deleted it or some automation deleted it).

Answer (score 25, accepted):

#### Option 1

Type

```
brew uninstall awscli
```

Then

```
brew install awscli
```

update python to 3.9.
look in the following [post.](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/awscli)

If this approach does not work for you, then try :

### Option 2

1. Go to https://www.python.org/ and use the GUI installer for your OS
2. `pip3 install awscli`

Comment: Thanks - but this makes no difference -- even after following the prompts of the install which said to do `brew link awscli` and `brew link --overwrite awscli`

Comment: You also need to update to python 3.9. Look in to the post i linked above

Comment: look in the following [post](https://medium.com/@yogeshdarji99/steps-to-install-awscli-on-mac-5bad783483a) as well it says that you have to give permissions to the config file.

Comment: I only saw the same install command when following that link - what is the specific command to update to python 3.9 please ?

Comment: you could also use the GUI downloader from python.org

Comment: That did it @CForce99 -- installing python using the Mac installer, and then running `pip3 install awscli` (which then finally worked) -- THANK YOU !!

OH - but now it turns out the `aws` command I'm using needs the CLI v2 .. I'll follow the instructions it's giving me there and hopefully get to the end...

Answer (score 14):

Another solution

```
# Reinstall awscli using your latest/current Python installation
brew reinstall awscli

# Overwrite the existing /usr/local/bin/aws with the new installation
brew link --overwrite awscli
```

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be to look into `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc`, look for line that looks like this:

```
export PATH=/Users/user_name/Library/Python/3.7/bin/:$PATH
```

Try commenting it first. If it works for you - remove it.

What this line does is prepending the lookup path for binaries, which in turn takes priority over brew installation.

Comment: Please note that "$" is missing in ":$PATH". This will remove all your path from the current session. Do not put this into bash_profile or similar

Comment: @Pateta, thank you. Edited answer to fix this.

Answer (score 5):

You probably don't need to reinstall awscli, but just update its Python path.

Check which Python versions are installed:

```
ls /usr/bin/python*
# /usr/bin/python2    /usr/bin/python3    /usr/bin/python2.7  /usr/bin/python3.6

python3 -V
# Python 3.6.8
```

Locate aws command, and update its python path:

```
which aws
# ~/.local/bin/aws

vi ~/.local/bin/aws
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

Try to call aws again:

```
$ aws
# usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [<subcommand> ...] [parameters]
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by reviewing my `.bash_profile`. There was an old entry which got invalid after updating python.

Just for the case someone also forgot to look the obvious first, like me... ;)